# Elasticsearch - Find all documents with aggregations results included in math operations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have 4 different aggregation queries where the results included in a math operation to find the total number required, pseudo example below. I need to find all the documents where the number is negative (e.g. -10).

number = agg1 + agg2 - agg3 - agg4

To keep it simple I will post two abbreviated aggregation queries.

Agg1:

```
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "aggs": {
    "queryAmount_1": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "amount"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "some_field": {
                    "query": "PayoutRequested"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Agg2:

```
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "aggs": {
    "queryAmount_2": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "amount"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "some_field": {
                    "query": "DonationRequested"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Somehow, I need to combine these in 1 query and grab the `amount` from the response for each aggregation grouped by `some_id` where the number result is negative.

Not sure if we can really achieve it but ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point would be the Pipeline aggregations and in specific have a look at [Cumulative sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html) and [Sum Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html). Hope this would help.